# Why am I getting invalid values when using flextable's tabulator() function?

Tags: r, flextable

I am new to R and using its library. I am trying to make a table where the headers are in the values of the columns itself and am using flextable.

Here is my goal (mock-up) where there are multiple header levels:
[image]

Here is the documentation on flextable's tabulator:
https://ardata-fr.github.io/flextable-book/tabulation.html

Here is my attempt (example data):

```
library(flextable)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(question = c("Food Satisfaction", "Food Satisfaction", "Food Satisfaction", "Food Satisfaction", "Food Satisfaction", "Food Satisfaction", "Food Satisfaction", "Food Satisfaction", "Food Satisfaction", "Food Satisfaction"),
                 column_one = c("Portion Size", "Portion Size", "Portion Size", "Portion Size", "Portion Size", "Portion Size", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region"),
                 column_two = c("Small", "Medium", "Large", "Small", "Medium", "Large", "West", "East", "West", "East"),
                 row = c("Pizza", "Pizza", "Pizza", "Hamburger", "Hamburger", "Hamburger", "Pizza", "Pizza", "Hamburger", "Hamburger"),
                 percent = c(0.83679353, 0.341159874, 0.084278807, 0.071733007, 0.363397833, 0.405083242, 0.094760815, 0.762002269, 0.782725923, 0.657853129),
                 standardError = c(0.824884898, 0.69073481, 0.664255159, 0.099570678, 0.735837865, 0.940523571, 0.933454698, 0.669219927, 0.669924278, 0.537262473))

cft <- tabulator(
  x = dat,
  rows = "row",
  columns = c("question", "column_one","column_two"),
  `P` = as_paragraph(percent),
  `SE` = as_paragraph(standardError)
)

ft <- as_flextable(cft)
ft
```

I am getting:

> Error in melt.data.table(as.data.table(dat), id.vars = c(columns,
> rows),  :    One or more values in 'id.vars' is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the table `df` you created but another named `dat` that does not contain the column named `row`.

Here is probably what you wanted to write:

```
library(flextable)
library(dplyr)

dat <- data.frame(question = c("Food Satisfaction", "Food Satisfaction", "Food Satisfaction", "Food Satisfaction", "Food Satisfaction", "Food Satisfaction", "Food Satisfaction", "Food Satisfaction", "Food Satisfaction", "Food Satisfaction"),
                 column_one = c("Portion Size", "Portion Size", "Portion Size", "Portion Size", "Portion Size", "Portion Size", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region"),
                 column_two = c("Small", "Medium", "Large", "Small", "Medium", "Large", "West", "East", "West", "East"),
                 row = c("Pizza", "Pizza", "Pizza", "Hamburger", "Hamburger", "Hamburger", "Pizza", "Pizza", "Hamburger", "Hamburger"),
                 percent = c(0.83679353, 0.341159874, 0.084278807, 0.071733007, 0.363397833, 0.405083242, 0.094760815, 0.762002269, 0.782725923, 0.657853129),
                 standardError = c(0.824884898, 0.69073481, 0.664255159, 0.099570678, 0.735837865, 0.940523571, 0.933454698, 0.669219927, 0.669924278, 0.537262473))

cft <- tabulator(
  x = dat,
  rows = "row",
  columns = c("question", "column_one","column_two"),
  `P` = as_paragraph(percent),
  `SE` = as_paragraph(standardError)
)

ft <- as_flextable(cft)
ft
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Embarrassed I missed such an obvious mistake. Is it possible to use "separate_with" to draw borders around specific column levels? I am trying to use "ft <- as_flextable(cft, separate_with = "column_one", sep_w = 0)" to separate out "Portion Size" and "Region".

Comment: no, sorry, argument `separate_with` is used to define `columns used to sepatate the groups with an horizontal line.` It only helps to draw horizontal lines. Maybe use `as_flextable(cft, sep_w = 0) |> theme_box()`

Comment: Got it, that will work. Not sure how feasible it would be but maybe a new parameter where you can separate which column level you want to add borders could be a great addition to flextable in the future. Excellent library and documentation, thank you!

Comment: Yeaaah, I agree. We are crawling on this subject since few months, trying to determine what kind of column selector is necessary and easy to use. Your use case will help:)